# Make file wrong for building libbot2 library

Tags: make, python-2.7, cmake

Let me describe my problems. 
So far I was building the MPNet which requests the `libbot2` library.

- [MPNet GitHub](https://github.com/ahq1993/MPNet)
- [libbot2 GitHub](https://github.com/libbot2/libbot2)

I have installed the [requirement libraries](https://github.com/libbot2/libbot2/blob/23613a8cfd87f796703552c1ecc019b485a83e44/README#L34) as followed:

```
        GLib 2.0+
        CMake
        LCM       (http://lcm.googlecode.com)
        Java      (Sun JDK or OpenJDK strongly preferred)
        Python
        GTK+ 2.0+ (required by bot2-vis)
        OpenGL    (required by bot2-vis)
        GLUT
        PyGTK
    libglib2.0-dev
    cmake
    sun-java6-jdk | default-jdk | openjdk-6-jdk
    python-dev
    python-gtk2
    libgtk2.0-dev
    mesa-common-dev
    libgl1-mesa-dev
    libglu1-mesa-dev
    freeglut3-dev
    libjpeg-dev
```

Here is my partial of environment setting.

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
    freeglut3-dev is already the newest version (2.8.1-3)
    libxi-dev is already the newest version (2:1.7.9-1)
    libxmu-dev is already the newest version (2:1.1.2-2)
    binutils is already the newest version (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.3)
    libglu1-mesa-dev is already the newest version (9.0.0-2.1build1)
    libgtk2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.24.32-1ubuntu1)
    libjpeg-dev is already the newest version (8c-2ubuntu8)
    freeglut3-dev is already the newest version (2.8.1-3)
    libgl1-mesa-dev is already the newest version (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3)
    libglib2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6)
    mesa-common-dev is already the newest version (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3)
    LCM version 1.4.0
```

When I used `sudo make`, I got this error. 
I found I cannot build successfully `bot2-vis` this stage.

```
-------------------------------------------
-- bot2-vis
-------------------------------------------
[  2%] Building C object src/bot_vis/CMakeFiles/bot2-vis.dir/viewer.c.o
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c: In function ‘bot_viewer_start_recording’:
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:136:21: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     self->movie_gzf = gzopen(self->movie_path, "w");
                     ^
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:137:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gzsetparams’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     gzsetparams(self->movie_gzf, Z_BEST_SPEED, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);
                 ^~~~
In file included from /home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:9:0:
/usr/include/zlib.h:1380:21: note: expected ‘gzFile {aka struct gzFile_s *}’ but argument is of type ‘struct gzFile_s **’
 ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT gzsetparams OF((gzFile file, int level, int strategy));
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c: In function ‘bot_viewer_stop_recording’:
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:173:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gzclose’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     gzclose(self->movie_gzf);
             ^~~~
In file included from /home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:9:0:
/usr/include/zlib.h:1631:24: note: expected ‘gzFile {aka struct gzFile_s *}’ but argument is of type ‘struct gzFile_s **’
 ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT    gzclose OF((gzFile file));
                        ^~~~~~~
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c: In function ‘on_gl_expose’:
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:498:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gzprintf’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         gzprintf(self->movie_gzf, "P6 %d %d %d\n", self->movie_width, self->movie_height, 255);
                  ^~~~
In file included from /home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:9:0:
/usr/include/zlib.h:1469:23: note: expected ‘gzFile {aka struct gzFile_s *}’ but argument is of type ‘struct gzFile_s **’
 ZEXTERN int ZEXPORTVA gzprintf Z_ARG((gzFile file, const char *format, ...));
                       ^~~~~~~~
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:502:21: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gzwrite’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             gzwrite(self->movie_gzf, &self->movie_buffer[offset], self->movie_stride);
                     ^~~~
In file included from /home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:9:0:
/usr/include/zlib.h:1447:21: note: expected ‘gzFile {aka struct gzFile_s *}’ but argument is of type ‘struct gzFile_s **’
 ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT gzwrite OF((gzFile file,
                     ^~~~~~~
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c: In function ‘on_button_press’:
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:600:5: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘BotEventHandler’
     BotEventHandler *best_handler = NULL;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:610:21: error: ‘best_handler’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘sa_handler’?
                     best_handler = handler;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                     sa_handler
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:610:21: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c: In function ‘on_motion_notify’:
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:690:2: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘BotEventHandler’
  BotEventHandler *best_handler = NULL;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/chieh/github/libbot2/bot2-vis/src/bot_vis/viewer.c:701:21: error: ‘best_handler’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘sa_handler’?
                     best_handler = handler;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                     sa_handler
src/bot_vis/CMakeFiles/bot2-vis.dir/build.make:322: recipe for target 'src/bot_vis/CMakeFiles/bot2-vis.dir/viewer.c.o' failed
make[4]: *** [src/bot_vis/CMakeFiles/bot2-vis.dir/viewer.c.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:130: recipe for target 'src/bot_vis/CMakeFiles/bot2-vis.dir/all' failed
make[3]: *** [src/bot_vis/CMakeFiles/bot2-vis.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ubuntu 18.04: building the MPNet which requests libbot2: libbot2 errors

```
sudo apt install openjdk11-jdk

cd lcm-1.4.0/ && mkdir build && cd build/
cmake -DLCM_ENABLE_TESTS=NO -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
make
.
[ 79%] Built target lcm-java
.
[ 90%] Built target lcm-python
[100%] Built target lcm-lua
```

Note: `LCM_ENABLE_TESTS` is a default option, and results in errors at 95% → test/java/hamcrest-core-1.3/org/hamcrest/core/AllOf.java . Hence `-DLCM_ENABLE_TESTS=NO`, i.e. the tests are disabled in the above build example.

*** Using a later version of `libbot2` https://github.com/ripl-ttic/libbot2

```
 git clone https://github.com/ripl-ttic/libbot2.git
 cd libbot2/
 sudo make BUILD_PREFIX=/usr         ## no errors
.
[ 91%] Completed 'bot2-lcm-utils'
[100%] Built target bot2-lcm-utils
```